# Obfuscated HTTP parser?

Tags: c, http, mongrel2

I am learning Go and I thought it would be a good exercise to implement my own HTTP 1.1 parser using Ragel and Go. I thought it would be a good idea to have a look at the code base of Mongrel2 to see how it's done.

The code for Mongrel's HTTP parser is [here](https://github.com/zedshaw/mongrel2/tree/master/src/http11) and I have a difficulty understanding the highlighted function [http11_parser.c](https://github.com/zedshaw/mongrel2/blob/master/src/http11/http11_parser.c#L91) which seems to do the actual HTTP processing.

My questions are as follows:

1. In plain English, what's the underlying idea behind the implementation? What does the code do?
2. Assuming that there is such a thing as idiomatic C, is this code a good example of it? If not, is there a reason for all these gotos, nested if and switches?

PS. Regarding Q2, the only explanation I could find for using the goto is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46638/722559). Note that my experience with C is 0.5 (on the scale from 1 - 10) which explains why I am having difficulty understanding this code!

Comment: Quite honestly, that code looks like it was generated by some program (something similar to `lex`, maybe?). Definitely not a coding style I would try to imitate.

Comment: @jxh You're right! This is a Ragel based parser. http11_parser.c is generated from [http11_parser.rl](https://github.com/zedshaw/mongrel2/blob/master/src/http11/http11_parser.rl) using the goto driven format. That explains it!

Comment: Nicely done. I was typing in a quick answer when you posted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighted function was generated by a program. Note the comment near the top of the file:

```
/** Machine **/


#line 254 "src/http11/http11_parser.rl"
```

So, you should look at the [`http11_parser.rl`](https://github.com/zedshaw/mongrel2/blob/master/src/http11/http11_parser.rl) file to see the input that generated this code. It is a lexer for an HTTP/1.1 request.

The idea behind the function is to parse an HTTP/1.1 request line and the headers that follow. Don't try to follow it to closely, focus on the pattern matching rules of the `r1` file, and compare it to the specification in the [HTTP/1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).